# Как правильно настроить .htaccess для nginx?

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, drupal

Пробую настроить redirect по user_agent заголовкам на разные страницы сайта. Например пользователя с устройства на ПО ios перенаправляет в раздел с контентом для ios, если android то в раздел android. У меня получилось только в стройках nginx через файл .vhosts обрубать доступ, но перенаправления внутри сайта вызывают циклическую переадресацию.

Выполнил действия по настройке .htaccess по этому [гайду](https://www.8host.com/blog/nastrojka-mod_rewrite-na-veb-servere-apache-v-centos-7/) в точности но у меня не работает(( Подскажите как правильно это сделать??

Comment: файл `.htaccess` — это «костыль» программы *apache*. исключительно только этой программы. и больше никакой.

Comment: `вызывают циклическую переадресацию` - посмотрите порядок переходов. можно в браузере, можно через `curl -Lvso /dev/null http://ваш-сайт`. Потом - рыться в конфигах. Или выложить их на SO :)

Comment: if ($http_user_agent ~ iPhone ) {  return 301 https//ios.my_domain.com$request_uri; } - как-то так. Апачевский htaccess здесь действительно не при чём.

Comment: @АлексейМ. ну этот код будет работать, если у тебя есть уже поддомен, типа мобильной версии сайта. А если в рамках одного основного домена, просто редирект на другую страницу как сделать?

Comment: @EvgenyPivovarov, if ($http_user_agent ~ iPhone ) { rewrite ^ $scheme://domain.com/ios/? permanent; } - что-то вроде этого надо. В сети посмотрите мануалы по редиректам в нжинксе. Вам нужен именно $http_user_agent.

Comment: @АлексейМ. спасибо большое, попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Файл .htaccess – это локальный конфигурационный файл вебсервера Apache. В отличие от главного конфигурационного файла (он может называться httpd.conf или apache2.conf), который позволяет выполнять настройку веб-вервера в целом, .htaccess даёт возможность конфигурировать настройки для отдельно взятых папок и пользователей. При этом инструкции (или директивы), содержащиеся в файле, выполняются для всех файлов или вложенных директорий, расположенных в одной директории с данным файлом (.htaccess). Если для какой-либо вложенной директории необходимы иные инструкции, в ней также можно создать файл .htaccess, и т. д.